# Arduino split char* based on delimiter to value

Tags: c++, c, arduino

thanks for your time, so I have a Char* from mqtt

I want to break this down into 3 seperate values

```
Char* mqttvalue
//Input Would be like the below for example. 
mqttvalue = (255,200,230);

// I would like to split the values into the below.
int 1 = 255
int 2 = 200
int 3 = 230
```

I've tried strtok with no luck. probably something really dumb but some guidance would help.

Thank you

Edit, what I tried.

```
//Dummy Value for testing 
Split("255,240,230");

//Split Value
void Split(char*  e) {
  String v[3];
  char *p;
  int i = 0;
  p = strtok(e, ",");
  while(p && i < 3)
  {
    v[i] = p;
     p = strtok(NULL, ",");
     Serial.println(p);
     ++i;
  };
  Serial.println(v[0]);
  Serial.println(v[1]);
  Serial.println(v[2]);
}
```

Comment: And pick C or C++. There are different functions used across each language.

Comment: @John I've updated it with more info now. So basically its just a string with 3 values in sent via mqtt. I jut want to assign each number between the commas to a int

Comment: Do you originally get your data as a `char *` or as a `String`?

Comment: @John I can get the data as anything Char* or String. I've tried with both but can't find a way to split and assign to seperate int's or values.

Comment: After looking at the `strtok` documentation your approach seems fine. What's the issue you're having? What output are you getting? "no luck" isn't very descriptive

Comment: @John i thought so to, the issue I get is only v[0] has a value of 255. v[1] & v[2] are both empty

Comment: `mqttvalue = (255,200,230);` what is it?

Comment: You call `split` with a string ilteral. That is not a valid parameter for `strtok` as it modifies the provided string.

Comment: Your pseudo code above does not make any sense. You talk about splitting strings but use integers to store the result. Also some integers in brackets are not the same as an input string. You should be a bit more precise when preparing your question.

Comment: For the life of me I don't know why there isn't a `std::tokenize` function in C++ that returns a `vector` of `string`s. That wouldn't help here, since Arduino eschews lots of the stdlib, but tokenization is something that people just want to work so they can solve their real problems.

Comment: I think the key may be with what @Gerhardh said. Create a test `char*` like `char test[] = "255,240,230";` and pass *that* to `Split`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code to the below from a string to char* its all now working.

```
 //Split Value
 void Split(char*  e) {
  char* v[3];
  char *p;
  int i = 0;
  p = strtok(rgb, ",");
  while(p && i < 3)
   {
    v[i] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    i++;
  };
  Serial.println(v[0]);
  Serial.println(v[1]);
  Serial.println(v[2]);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is quite often asked question and I'd propose more like using wrapper class inheriting [Stream interface](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/) on C string (and it can be initialized from Arduino `String` object too).

However usage with Arduino `String` class is tricky as the original String shouldn't be altered during usage of `StringStream`, but it's possible to reinitialize it again. Using rvalue (`String` literal, passed into the class) is forbidden by using non const reference as the parameter of `setData` method and constructor.

However it's not tested much, so there might be some mistakes. The copy/move constructor and assigment is ommited (and it shouldn't be :D), also using  `operator=(String&)` and `operator=(const char*)` would be more intuitive interface for it.

```cpp
class StringStream : public Stream
{
  public:
    StringStream()
    {
      setTimeout(1);
    }

    StringStream(const char * str)
    {
      setData(str);
    }

    StringStream(const char * begin, const char * end)
    {
      setData(begin, end);
    }

    explicit StringStream(String & view) // cannot be String literal (rvalue) and it gets invalidated if you change original String
    {
      setData(view);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////
    inline void setData(const char * begin, const char * end)
    {
      m_start = begin;
      m_end = end;
      setTimeout(1);
    }

    inline void setData(const char * begin)
    {
      setData(begin, begin + strlen(begin));
    }

    inline void setData(String & view)
    {
      setData(view.c_str(), m_start + view.length());
    }

    //////////////////////////////////
    // Stream Interface:
    virtual int available() override
    {
      return m_end - m_start;
    }

    virtual int read() override
    {
      if (m_start < m_end)
      {
        return *(m_start++);
      }
      return -1;
    }

    virtual int peek() override
    {
      if (m_start < m_end)
      {
        return *m_start;
      }
      return -1;
    }

    virtual size_t write(uint8_t) override {
      return 0;
    }

  protected:
    const char * m_start{0};
    const char * m_end{0};
};
```

And the test program would be like:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Output:");

  StringStream test{" 144, 7899, -5478"};
  Serial.println(test.parseInt());
  Serial.println(test.parseInt());
  Serial.println(test.parseInt());

  test.setData("1 2");
  Serial.println(test.parseInt());
  Serial.println(test.parseInt());

  delay(2000);
}
```